# Экранирование // в clojure

Tags: парсер, экранирование, clojure

не могу заэкранировать '// в clojure. IDE пишет, что invalid symbol. Подскажите, как можно это исправить?

```
(def OPERATORS
  {'+      Add
   '-      Subtract
   '*      Multiply
   '/      Divide
   'negate Negate
   'sinh   Sinh
   'cosh   Cosh
   '**     Pow
   '//    Log
   })
```

ругается только на //

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из [документации](https://clojure.org/reference/reader)

> #### Symbols
>
> - `'/'` has special meaning, it can be used once in the middle of a symbol to separate the namespace from the name, e.g. my-namespace/foo.
>     '/' by itself names the division function.
>
> #### Literals
>
> - Keywords - Keywords are like symbols

Приведённая цитата не очень чётко, но всё же постулирует, что в символах и ключевых словах символ `/` может встречаться только один раз.